# SQL Select statement for NOT IN multiple values

Tags: sql

Im trying to Select some values from a table and I need to exclude other values.

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 8 AND NOT
IN(SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id =
1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5)
```

As you can see I want the term_taxonomy_id from object_id where object_id is not 1-5.

Im not sure what to do here and any help is apreciated!

Edit:
Here is the complete query that gets the correct values:

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 8 AND 
term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) )
```

Comment: `WHERE object_id = 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5` won't do what you expect, you need `WHERE object_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` instead.

Comment: You should start with some SQL Tutorials.   You clearly have a misunderstanding about some of the basic syntax.

Comment: I tried this but am still getting an error..

SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 8 AND NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

@Tab Alleman, you are right Im not familiar with AND NOT IN and how to use it, any guidance is apreciated!

Comment: @ander2ed, my query is run in a foreach loop where I want the corresponding id for each run, but I dont want it returned if its 1-5. This is my php for it without the deselect of 1-5.
    foreach ($all_cart_products as $product => $v) {
    $results[] = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM     wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id ="' . $v['product_id'] . '"');
     }

Im sorry this is my first post, im still getting the hang of how to highlight code etc

Comment: Please post updates such as new code and information in an edit to your original post rather than in the comments. This makes it easier for Stack Overflow readers to gain all necessary information and better answer your questions.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman will do, added the correct query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` and explicit comparisons:

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE object_id = 8 AND 
      object_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id
                        FROM wp_term_relationships
                        WHERE object_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                       )
```

Comment: I bet you guessed wrong, and that it's term_taxonomy_id that needs to not be IN (the subquery).

Comment: My table looks like this:
<code>Object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order
1              | 1                            |0
8              | 2                            |0
8              | 6                            |0
11             | 2                            |0
11            | 7                            |0<code>

Your answer gives me term_taxonomy_id 2 and 6. I do not want the 2 since that is in range of 1-5. Do I make sense?

Comment: I think I got it. With the help of your code I could change object_id in the subquery and retrieve the values I needed. Thank you!

Here is the complete query; SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 8 AND term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) )